# Can I ask the user for a number, and paste the image of the correspondant number into a blanc image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to assign letters or numbers to an image, for example the letter : "A" is the image with an A, the number "0" is the image with a 0 etc..
And I would like to ask with an input a number, for example 0 and python will link this number to the right image ( the image with a 0 ) and paste that image to a blanc image.

I already know how to merge ( or combine ) an image with another, I use Pillow :

```
from PIL import Image

background_img = Image.open("blanc.png")   # the blanc image
IM0 = Image.open("0.jpg")   # The image with a 0
area2 = (0, 208)  # Where the 0 will go on the blanc image
background_img.paste(IM0, area2)   # Paste the 0
background_img.save("Final.png")   # Save the final image
```

And I know how to ask something with an input

```
number = input("what number do you want ?")
```

But I don't know how to assign ( or link ) the number I will write in the input, to a specific image..

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: use str(number) and append it to the string.

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the answer, but can you explain a little bit more please ? I didn't understand what you said

Comment: basically, if a user inputs A, then you want to open A.jpg and if user enters "0", then you want to open 0.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, all that's missing is the **name** of the image. For example, if the user has entered the value "1", you need to find an image with the name "1.jpg".

If that is correct, you could accomplish it easily with the following:

```
file_name_fmt = "{v}.jpg"
val = input()
file_name = file_name_fmt.format(v=val)
if file_name in list_of_images:
    img = Image.open(file_name)
```

**EDIT**

```
from PIL import Image

file_name_fmt = "{v}.jpg"

area2 = (0, 208)  # Where the 0 will go on the blanc image
background_img = Image.open("blanc.png")   # the blanc image

val = input("Enter a character for an image representation: ")
file_name = file_name_fmt.format(v=val)
if file_name in list_of_images:
    img = Image.open(file_name)
else:
    raise FileNotFoundError("The file specified doesn't exist")

background_img.paste(img, area2)   # Paste the 0
background_img.save("Final.png")   # Save the final image
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! This is completely what I research! I'm a complete beginner, so I did not completely understand your code, how can I add this to my code ? And how can I "link" your code to my "merging image" code ? Sorry to bother you !

Comment: Seeing that you are a beginner with python, I would suggest some "beginner course" with python, specifically regarding basic CLI (command line interface) creation with python. I will try to make the code snippet a little clearer.

Comment: Thank you Eviatar Zweigenberg ! Yes I will watch some beginner course, thanks to you I already learned new things with python so again thank you very much !